# Joining 2 tables and adding price to give total revenue in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, sum

probably a simple query for someone to answer but I'm new at this and a bit stuck!

Trying to map from one table to another and sum together numbers in a column from Table 1. For example:

```
Table 1:
Item_ID  Price
I0001    3.50
I0002    2.50

Table 2:
Item_ID  Date_sold
I0001    10/11/14
I0002    12/11/14
```

What I want to do is tell MySQL that where 'Date_sold' is 'not null' in Table 2, to identify 'Item_id', match this back to table 1, read the 'Price' column in that row, and then add the results together for total revenue.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Luckily date_sold is never not NULL

Comment: can you show us desire output?

Comment: where is the total revenue field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ll try something like that :

```
SELECT t1.Item_ID, SUM(Price) AS Total
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table 2 t2
ON t1.Item_ID = t2.Item_ID
WHERE t2.Sold_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Item_ID;
```

You will get the grand total by item if you add the group by statement.

If you only want the grand total :

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS GrandTotal
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table 2 t2
ON t1.Item_ID = t2.Item_ID
WHERE t2.Sold_date IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Your second option of Grand Total worked for me, and that's what I wanted. Thanks a million ;)

Comment: Do not forget to valid my answer if it's ok for you ! (:

Answer (score 0):

You could `join` both tales on the `item_id`, and then `group by` to sum the price:

```
SELECT   date_sold, SUM(price)
FROM     table_2
JOIN     table_1 on table_2.item_id = table_1.item_id
WHERE    date_sold IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY date_sold
```

Answer (score 0):

select sum(table1.price) as revenue from table1 join table2 on table1.item_id=table2.item_id where table2.data_sold is not null